# GCloud Function & GStorage: sending downloaded file error: 'write after end'

Tags: express, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

My goal is to retrieve a file from Google Storage and then send it back via response. The problem is that, when I launch this function for the first time it crashes with `Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end`. The next executions work fine.

```
exports = module.exports = region(defaultRegion).https.onRequest(async (req, res): Promise<void> => {
  const [authError] = await to(handleAuth(req, res));
  if (authError) {
    res.status(500).send(authError.message);
    return;
  }

  const { assetId, contentType, path } = req.query;

  const file = bloqifyStorage.bucket().file(`assets/${assetId}/${path}`);

  const fileExists = (await file.exists())[0];
  if (!fileExists) {
    res.status(404).send(`${path} was not found`);
    return;
  }

  const fileStream = file.createReadStream();

  fileStream.pipe(res).on('end', (): void => {
    res.setHeader('content-type', contentType);
  });
});
```

What am I missing here?

Edit: removing the set header doesn't solve it. Ex:

```
const fileStream = file.createReadStream();

// res.setHeader('content-type', contentType);
fileStream.pipe(res).on('error', (e): void => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

It will print the same error.